# Keep calling service/broadcast from each other

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm building a simple app, that keep monitoring the media level, and adjust it to be 20% of the maximum level all the time, if the user increased,it should back to 20%again.

Th concept I followed is doing the monitoring process via a service, once this service is destroyed it calls a broadcast receiver, which in its turn calls the receiver again, and so on, as endless cycle, but looks something wrong in the code below,soit is not working as desired, and service/broadcast not keep calling each others!

I started the `mainActivity` as:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val audio = this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
        val level = audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)

        val maxVolume = audio.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
        val percent = 0.2f
        val twintyVolume = (maxVolume * percent).toInt()

        if ( level > twintyVolume) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"audio level is $level", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,twintyVolume,0)
        }

        this.startService(Intent(this, VolumeCheck::class.java))
    }
}
```

The above make initial check and reduce the media volume to 20% of the max volume, then start the service, which is doing the same with the below code:

```
class VolumeCheck : Service() {

    private lateinit var context: Context

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        context = this
        Toast.makeText(this, "service created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
        Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        val audio = context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
        val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()


     //   Thread().run {
            val maxVolume = audio.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
            val percent = 0.2f
            val twintyVolume = (maxVolume * percent).toInt()
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying) {
                val level = audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
                if ( level > twintyVolume) {
                    Toast.makeText(context,"audio level is $level", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,twintyVolume,0)
                }
            }
      //      Thread.sleep(3000)
     //   }
        stopSelf()
        return Service.START_STICKY
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        //TODO for communication return IBinder implementation
        return null
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        Toast.makeText(this, "service done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        val intent = Intent("com.kortex.mediafix.BootUpReceiver")
        sendBroadcast(intent)
    }
}
```

Once the service is destroyed, it calls the boot broadcast receiver, which in its turn call the service again:

```
class BootUpReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        context.startService(Intent(context, VolumeCheck::class.java))
    }
}
```

The `Manifest` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.kortex.mediafix">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".BootUpReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".VolumeCheck" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using `ContentObserver` that is called from the `service`, so my code now is:

1. `MainActivity` to launch the app, and do first time adjustment, and to start the service:

   ```
   class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

       val audio = this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
       val level = audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)

       val maxVolume = audio.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
       val percent = 0.2f
       val twintyVolume = (maxVolume * percent).toInt()

       if ( level > twintyVolume) audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,twintyVolume,0)

       Toast.makeText(this,"Audio level adjusted to 20% instead of $level", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

       this.startService(Intent(this, VolumeCheck::class.java))

       finish()
      }
   }
   ```
2. `Broadcast` to start the app and the service each time the device is rebooted:

   ```
   class BootUpReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {

   override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
       context.startService(Intent(context, VolumeCheck::class.java))
      }
   }
   ```
3. `Service` to register and call the observer:

   ```
   class VolumeCheck : Service() {

   private lateinit var context: Context
   private lateinit var myObserver: VolumeOnserver


   override fun onCreate() {
       super.onCreate()
       context = this
       // Define the VolumeOnserver
       myObserver = VolumeOnserver(context, Handler())
       Toast.makeText(this, "service created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

   override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
       super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
       Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       // Register the VolumeOnserver for setting changes
       contentResolver.registerContentObserver(android.provider.Settings.System.CONTENT_URI ,true, myObserver);

       return Service.START_STICKY
   }

   override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
       return null
   }

   override fun onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy()

       // Unregister the VolumeOnserver
       contentResolver.unregisterContentObserver(myObserver);
      }
   }
   ```
4. `Observer` that observe any changes in the `settings` and check the media volume and adjust it if required:

   ```
   class VolumeOnserver (context: Context, h: Handler?): ContentObserver(h) {

   private val context = context

   override fun onChange(selfChange: Boolean) {
       onChange(selfChange, uri = null)
   }

   // Implement the onChange(boolean, Uri) method to take advantage of the new Uri argument.
   override fun onChange(selfChange: Boolean, uri: Uri?) {
       // Handle change.
       val audio = context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
       val level = audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)

       val maxVolume = audio.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
       val percent = 0.2f
       val twintyVolume = (maxVolume * percent).toInt()

       if ( level > twintyVolume) audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,twintyVolume,0)

       // Toast.makeText(context,"audio level is $level", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
      }
   }
   ```

The `Manifest` file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.kortex.mediafix">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".BootUpReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
               <action android:name="com.kortex.mediafix.BootUpReceiver" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".VolumeCheck" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And my running app is [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kortex.mediafix).

But have an issue it is not stable, I the user insist to change the volume, after many trials the service and/or the observer is/are no more working till the app is restarted.

Answer (score 0):

```
val intent = Intent("com.kortex.mediafix.BootUpReceiver")
```

This line does not call your broadcast receiver but rather makes an intent with intent action as "com.kortex.mediafix.BootUpReceiver"

Change your BootUpReceiver's entry in manifest to receive this action

```
<receiver android:name=".BootUpReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <action android:name="com.kortex.mediafix.BootUpReceiver" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it, without `Service` is to call `ContentObserver` from `BroadcastReceiver`

1. `BroadcastReceiver`:

   class BootUpReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {

   ```
   override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
       val myObserver = VolumeOnserver(context, Handler())

       // Register the VolumeOnserver for setting changes
       context.contentResolver.registerContentObserver(
               android.provider.Settings.System.CONTENT_URI ,true,
               myObserver)
      }
   }
   ```
2. `ContentObserver`:

   class VolumeOnserver (context: Context, h: Handler?): ContentObserver(h) {

   ```
   private val context = context

   override fun onChange(selfChange: Boolean) {
       onChange(selfChange, uri = null)
   }

   // Implement the onChange(boolean, Uri) method to take advantage of the new Uri argument.
   override fun onChange(selfChange: Boolean, uri: Uri?) {
       // Handle change.
       val audio = context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
       val level = audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)

       val maxVolume = audio.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
       val percent = 0.2f
       val twintyVolume = (maxVolume * percent).toInt()

       if ( level > twintyVolume) audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,twintyVolume,0)
       }
   }
   ```
3. `MainActivity`:

   class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

   ```
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

       val audio = this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
       val level = audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)

       val maxVolume = audio.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
       val percent = 0.2f
       val twintyVolume = (maxVolume * percent).toInt()

       if ( level > twintyVolume) audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,twintyVolume,0)

       finish()
      }
   }
   ```